# Difference between full sync and AD import job

Tags: sharepoint, on-premises-instances

I have SharePoint on prem environment. I want to understand difference between user profile active directory import job and user profile full sync. Are these same? As I have created new property mapping and once AD import job runs, I cannot see values to new property in user profile. But when I run full sync from central admin , I can see values to property.

I ran AD import job but no output. If I run user profile full sync I can see values

Answer (score 0):

They are not same.

Active Directory Import is an one-way import, it imports data form AD to CA, but you can't export values from CA to AD.

SharePoint Profile Synchronization is a two-way sync, it imports data form AD to CA (values always same as AD), and exports values from CA to AD (values always same as user profile in CA).

Comment: If 2 way then don't understand the usage. Like import to CA and write back to AD again. It's either of the 2 at a time if I am not mistaken.